# Android phone won't successfully connect to PC (for OS upgrade)

Tags: android

I am trying to upgrade HTC Desire HD phone's OS into v3.But my laptop fails installing some sort of MT6516 driver. On the Web I can't find it to download.

I bought HTC Desire HD on Amazon.co.uk. I am trying to install Gingerbread OS (v3). I am trying to refer to the following page for instructions: http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/how-to-update-htc-desire-to-android-2-3-gingerbread-50004625/
This phone supports Dual SIM.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What os is the laptop, and where is it trying to install the drivers from?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 bits. The OS just gives me a notice on the screen that the device driver was not successfully installed; no driver found referring to MT6516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most applications written for earlier versions of windows are likely to run on the "64 bit" version of windows 7 but you may need a specific 64-bit version of the device driver to connect your PC to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, but try installing the "HTC Sync" software from the HTC website.  It may include the correct driver.

If you are putting the phone into some sort of bootloader mode you may need a different driver though.

Comment: The latest HTC Sync is on my laptop already. It makes no difference to the installation. During the process of installation on the screen it is written 'loading bootloader' or so. The error says I need MT6516 driver. In fact the phone is set to 'debug mode'. I could not find 'Sync mode' as per tutorial on how to upgrade the OS.

Comment: This may be a driver offered only to service centers as part of a "Phone Support Tool" software package to perform maintenance on phones.  When I worked ast Sprint, the service software we used had all kinds of "USB cable" drivers for all different types of phones.  Unfortunately, no way to get the software legally without being a Sprint service center.  There's a good chance you probably won't find this driver through any official channels.

Comment: Is that a deadlock regarding OS upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more detail about the phone and the upgrade you are trying to run? All drivers needed for normal unlocked usage and upgrade of an HTC Desire HD should be included with HTC Sync.

Upgrades should only be done automatically by the phone, from a manual update check in the phone settings, or by running a program on your Windows machine called an RUU provided by customer care. The HTC Desire HD is an Android OS phone, but the 3.x versions of Android OS are for tablets only.

Do you have any links or details to: where you bought the phone and it's model, what OS you are trying to install on it, if there is a page with any instructions you are using, etc.. Does the phone you own support dual SIM cards? Does it say HDC instead of HTC on it? These last two are signs that it is a clone, a phone made to look similar to an HTC Desire HD, but that is not really one. They are often found in China or bought off eBay for low prices.

Sorry I can't answer right off the bat. :)

Comment: I have added more info to my initial question.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Unfortunately, your phone is not an HTC phone, as the official phone does not support dual SIM and does not use the MTK6513 processor. The instructions you linked will not work. There are a large number of non-HTC phones based on MTK6513, if you Google that and updating you can find some resources like these: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=18046607 http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1470771